# How to Change Default Copyright Template

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode-template

Whenever I make a new file in xcode, it puts something like this at the top of the file:

```
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2008.  All rights reserved.
```

How can I change that to something useful?

Update: [found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode#33789).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of Xcode 3, it will use the "company" field from your Address Book card.

Answer (score 14):

Follow these steps to change the copyright:

[image]

Note: The change is for new files that you create, so you will need to update the ones that had been previously created manually.

Answer (score 4):

As of Xcode 6.1.1 this can be changed by clicking on the main .xcodeproj file in the project view (the blue one). The right panel has a field called 'Organization' that will be used for the copyright template. This panel may be hidden, and can be made visible with a button in the upper right corner.