# Resetting copyright macro in Xcode

Tags: xcode, copyright-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting copyright statement on a per-project basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991035/setting-copyright-statement-on-a-per-project-basis)

How do you reset the copyright macro that gets placed into the header of each new file?  Mine still say **MyCompanyName** which is irritating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[First result](http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=2003092411095361) when Googling `xcode __mycompanyname__`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!  I knew it was simple.  I was looking for something in preferences.

Answer (score 3):

There's a per-project setting in Xcode for that (available starting Xcode 3.2, but I may be wrong about the exact version).

```
project -> info -> general tab -> "Organization Name"
```