# XCode 3.2 Ruby and Python templates

Tags: python, ruby, cocoa, xcode, pyobjc

Under xcode 3.2 my ObjectiveC + Python/Ruby projects can still be opened updated and compiled, but you cannot create new projects.

Given that all traces of ruby and python are missing from xcode 3.2 (ie create project and add new ruby/python file), is there an easy way to get the templates installed again?

I found some info about copying them into a folder somewhere, but I cant seem to get it to work, I suspect the folder location has changed for 3.2.

Comment: Even after installing the templates, for me, none of the RubyCocoa/PyObjC features that connect IB and XCode together are working – did you get it working?

Comment: The only way I could get things working is create an empty python/ruby project in xcode 3.1, then make copies of this project folder for every new project you work on. And 3.2 lets you rename the project so you can have proper names for eacn new project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The folder for application templates in 3.2 is:
/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application

Templates for python are at:
http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc-xcode/Project%20Templates/

use:

```
$svn co <address of template you want> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application/<Folder you want it in>
```

e.g.

```
$svn co http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc-xcode/Project%20Templates/Cocoa-Python%20Document-based%20Application/ /Developer/Library/Xcode/Project\ Templates/Application/Cocoa-Python\ NSDocument\ based\ Application
```

Answer (score 5):

[Here's the word](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Xcode-users/2009/Aug/msg00517.html) on this from Chris Espinosa on the Xcode-Users mailing list:

> We are deemphasizing Cocoa-Python and
>   Cocoa-Ruby, though existing project
>   will continue to build in Xcode.  You
>   can duplicate one of your existing
>   projects and use the new Rename
>   command to start a new project.
>
> Bugs filed against the removal of
>   these templates will be duplicated to
>    No
>   Python/Ruby templates in Xcode, and
>   we'll use that bug to gauge the need
>   for that support in the future.

I'd say file a bug report at [https://bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa) to voice your opinion on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Beginning with Xcode 3.2, Apple decided to not include project and file templates from 3rd party projects (including PyObjC, RubyCocoa or MacRuby). Since these template files were often updated more frequently than Xcode's release cycle, the templates shipped with Xcode were often out of date. Developers are now encouraged to install the templates directly from those projects' repositories. PyObjC templates are currently available only in SVN, though the PyObjC devs intend to make them available on the website "soon". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589757/add-new-templates-in-xcode) question details how to install new templates.

Answer (score 1):

- Download the [Cocoa-Ruby Templates](http://rubycocoa.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rubycocoa/trunk/src/template/ProjectBuilder/) to your '/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application/Ruby Application/' and '/Developer/Library/Xcode/File Templates/Ruby/' directories.
- Install the latest version of [Ruby Cocoa](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rubycocoa/files/).

More info can be found on the [Ruby Cocoa website](http://rubycocoa.sourceforge.net/HomePage).

Answer (score 0):

The above coments were all good and helpful but didn't really help. Easiest thing I could find is to create an empty python/ruby project in xcode 3.1, then make copies of this project folder for every new project you work on.

When you open the new/blank project, 3.2 has a new feature that lets you rename the project so you can have proper names for eacn new project.