# Update copyright (header comment) for all files in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode

I used `IDETemplateMacros.plist` ([from here](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/07/xcode-9-text-macros/)) to have proper headers while creating new files. But I need to update everything already created. Is there any proper way which `XCode` offers, or I should write some custom script?

Comment: You can hit `command+4` to bring up the left side menu with search function and then select `find & replace text`, then select `in workspace` or `in project` depending on what you need. Xcode will then search through all files and allow you to easily replace strings.

Comment: please have a look on this url, find the answer with 7 up votes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381149/changing-the-default-header-comment-license-in-xcode

Comment: @aBilal17 as commented:"This only changes the organisation and not the license etc."

Comment: @LinusGeffarth find\replace won't work, because each file has filename inside copyright.