# Create Custom Header in Swift Package. no IDETemplteMacros.plist exists in Swift Package

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

In Xcode Project we have IDETemplteMacros.plist  to set the header for every file we create it takes that content with copy rights text. In Swift Package we don't have any option to create such header

Comment: tried creating IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist in the xcshareddata in .swiftpm/Xcode/xcshareddata folder still no luck. used https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev91a7a31fc doc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the default header comment license in Swift Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614785/changing-the-default-header-comment-license-in-swift-package)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to place `IDETemplateMacros.plist` in the `xcshareddata` folder of the package's generated workspace within the .swiftpm folder. eg.

`<PackageFolder>/.swiftpm/xcode/package.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDETemplateMacros.plist`

This works for me in Xcode 13.0.

Comment: don't see package.xcworkspace inside .swiftpm folder. I have only below folder.
.swiftpm/xcode/xcshareddata

Comment: Not working for me in Xcode 14.1.

Comment: Not working for me in Xcode 14.1 either. Has anyone found a stable long-term fix for this?