# Is there a macro that Xcode automatically sets in debug builds?

Tags: xcode, debugging, macros

So I can write code like this:

```
#ifdef [whatever]
   // do stuff that will never show up in the production version
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume that debug builds always use `gcc -O0` (this is normally the case, but there may be odd exceptions where someone has changed the optimisation level for debug builds) then you can do this:

```
#if __OPTIMIZE__
  // ... non-debug stuff ... 
#else
  // ... debug stuff ...
#endif
```

Comment: I've read that __OPTIMIZE__ is not set anymore in XCode 4 all the time. Do you confirm this ?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing useful per default, but you can set a `DEBUG` macro for debug builds in the *"Preprocessor Macros"* of the targets build settings and then do:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  // do stuff
#endif
```

If you want to automate that, edit the project templates in `"/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates"`:

- Find the `XCBuildConfiguration` section(s) for which `name = Debug;`.
- In the `buildSettings` add `DEBUG` to the list for `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` if it exists
- Otherwise add `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = (DEBUG);` to the `buildSettings`

For per-user customizations and to avoid them being overwritten, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode).

Comment: Works obviously . . . the problem is that then I have to set the DEBUG macro in every target of every project to which I port the code in question.

Comment: i believe this is set by default now (DEBUG=1)