# How to use diffrent types of Log in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I would like to know how many types od log are there and when to use what type log .Till now i have been using NSLog but when i finally submit the applcation to app store i need to search for the nslog and need to close them all .I have heard of Dlog , Alog but dont know how to use.So is there any solution which would set Log off when we select release, debug modes.It would be great if yuo can provide me a code for diffent Log types and how to use them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define project-wide macros in your `<project>.pch` file. For example:

```
#if DEBUG
#define DLog(format, ...) NSLog((format), ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DLog(format, ...)
#endif
```

(This assumes you're setting the DEBUG macro in your debug builds: [Is there a macro that Xcode automatically sets in debug builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223753/is-there-a-macro-that-xcode-automatically-sets-in-debug-builds/3223772#3223772))

Then you can use `DLog` anywhere you've used `NSLog` for messages that should only appear in your debug builds, in your release builds they will be gone.

More sophisticated versions can be found in the answers to the question: [How to print out the method name and line number and conditionally disable NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969130/nslog-tips-and-tricks/969291#969291)

Also, you could [roll your own logging class](http://objectuser.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/a-single-class-logger-in-objective-c/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to turn off NSLogs in your final build.
Here is a solution that has been posted before:

```
    #ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```