# Xcode uses old version of templates?

Tags: xcode, templates

My install of Xcode 3.2.3 created a project with different template files than those of my classmates. We all created a navigation-based app that used core data.

I suspect that my templates are somehow left over from previous installs, whereas my classmates all have current templates.

Anyone else experienced this? Any suggestions for making sure I have the current templates?

Answer (score 0):

If there are copies or customized versions in

`~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/`

they will be preferred over global (updated) versions, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode/).

Comment: No, there are no templates there.

Comment: @Scott: Sorry then, that was my best guess. Clean remove and reinstall the newest version?