# How to modify the Xcode new file headers that specify the copyright etc?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change templates in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode)

How can I change the commented out text of the source code files I created in xcode. The ones that say "Created By..., Copyright 2011 ...

**UPDADE:**
I am using Xcode 4

Comment: Please clarify if you are using XCode 3 or 4. If it's 3, the link from Simon is correct. If it's 4, that's a different issue.

Comment: In Xcode 4 this is not a duplicate! The answer from Mangold is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to change the name or company name, modify the "Me" record in your Address Book.