# Change case in Xcode file templates?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, file, templates

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode):

Is it possible to use the lowercase version of an identifier that appears in those templates?  For example, to create a template that allows a user to create something like this, while entering Foo only once:

Filename: Foo.h

```
@interface Foo: SuperclassOfFoo {
}

-(Foo*) foo;

@end
```

Comment: To clarify:  You want to have the user go through the standard template chooser, entering only the word "Foo", and have the template produce the result you listed, with a method that has lower and uppercase versions of the word entered.

Comment: Correct.  If it works, I'll do more than that with it.  But that would be a great start.

Comment: did you come up with a solution ? I'm struggling with the same thing

Comment: Gave up on it.  Partly the problem is that the templates disappear with upgrades.  I know I could bring them back, but it's a pain, because I have to find the location, and it has changed at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I dont get it but a capitalized method name is bad :D besides it should start with a verb maybe