# How to save an XCode project as a template to use for other apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, templates

Is it possible to create a template from an existing XCode project to use again and again but with different app names?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this link [Cocoa dev: Design your own Xcode project templates](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/04/cocoa-dev-design-your-own-xcode-project-templates.ars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking 2 different questions. First: You can't. Second: Yes.

AFAIK you can't save an Xcode project and get a template automagically. You can use a project as a starting point for a new template.

Creating an Xcode template is a manual process, you'll need to rename lots of stuff, and follow undocumented naming conventions. The best place to learn about Xcode templates is the  default templates provided by Xcode.

You can start here: [Change templates in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode)