# Recognizing Installed C++ library in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode

I've downloaded and installed [google-sparse_has_map](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) with

```
./configure 
make
make install
```

As instructed, without a problem, but when I included it in XCode, like this:

```
#include <google/sparse_hash_map>
```

I receive the following error:

> **Google/sparse_hash_map: No such file or directory.**

It is installed in */usr/local/include/*

how do I *show* this directory to XCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at my graphic below:

[image: Settings]

You need to tell Xcode where the library and the include files are.  Add paths to the "Header Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" of your project settings.

Comment: how can I add this for all my projects by default? Thank you!

Comment: Myself, I wouldn't add this to my default (you never know what old, outdated or crazy stuff you might accidentally pick up from `/usr/local`), but if you are determined to make it happen, check out [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode) about modifying the template apps & projects served up by Xcode and you may be able to add in search paths there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your project where to find the include folder

"/I /usr/local/include/" or "-I /usr/local/include/"

Of course it depends on where the folder is relative to the project directory.

From http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=227636 the XCode compiler options can be found by doing the following:

> ```
> Select the name of your project from the Groups and Files list.
> Click the Get Info button in the project window toolbar. An information panel for the project will open.
> Click the Build tab in the information panel.
> Choose GNU C/C++ Compiler from the Collection pop-up menu.
> ```