# How to bulk update the copyright message that appears on top of each file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, templates, copyright-display

I've visited [Change templates in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode) , but I don't think it is exactly what I want to do.

Xcode adds a copyright message to the top of each file that you create and populates it with fields like name, copyright etc, which it reads from somewhere.

I want to know:
1) How to bulk change the copyright message on files that have already been created.
2) Change the settings, so that for new files it specifies different name / company in template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) find and replace :(

2) the name and company are taken from your card in the Address Book app.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Search Navigator. You can do regex based searches, customise the scope of the search and then replace values, including group values from the search.