# How to change the previously selected ios developer team

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor, apple-developer

ı use (ionic) capacitor , when i first tested on xcode i selected the team **'x'** account and ran it(There is no problem).Then i buy for developer account for **'y'** account , then i select team **'y'* after select new team ı got 2 errors

Errors :

1 : Failed to register bundle identifier
The app identifier "com.Appname" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

2:No profiles for 'com.Appname' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.Appname'.

I dont want to change Bundle Identifier.I've been searching for 2 days and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Maybe I'm late here, but have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar problem but I'm not sure if it's actually the same.

First thing I recommend to do is go to settings inside the XCode app and make sure you are logged into XCode with your user (or the user inside the team you want to select).

The problem you are facing says that there are no Bundles with that name, so probably you should remove the actual identifier and try to register a new one with **exactly** the same name.

Take a look on this topics, maybe they help you:

[Xcode - Change Company Name and Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245689/xcode-change-company-name-and-username)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/bundle_ids