# Changing Copyright Comments in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I want to change Copyright text to a specific text in all the existing files
I have found an answer of this at -- [Batch replace copyright comment in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622208/batch-replace-copyright-comment-in-xcode)

But Unfortunately, the download does not exist now. Could anyone provide me the script or any other method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I search/replace in multiple .txt files quickly from Terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895169/can-i-search-replace-in-multiple-txt-files-quickly-from-terminal)

Comment: @Shai Could you provide a more closer answer, as i have not much experience on sed,grep commands..

Comment: @Shai i think we need to identify -- All lines at the beginning of file that starts with // (commented lines) and replace them with /* text_info */ in Xcode

Comment: if you want to batch replace text in multiple files, use sed as mentioned above sed -i '.bak' 's/old copyright text/new copyright text/g' *.h

Comment: @Shai Copyright text is not fixed in every file..

Comment: Ahh I see... oh well, you'll need to find a more complex solution then :-)

Comment: @Shai You marked it as a duplicate and i think that's why no one provided any answers..Could you please remove that?

Comment: won't change much but sure...