# Using @import ... as default instead of #import <...>

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import

When creating a new Objective-C class, XCode inserts this line into the .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Instead, I want it to be the following automatic:

```
@import Foundation;
```

Where can I set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode inserts the imports because this is how it is defined in the "new file templates". Instead of changing those built-in templates you should clone them and make your own, with adjusted import statement.

Look at this answer how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33743/396578

Comment: The template definition for imports is a bit complicated. Could you also explain how exactly should be the template changed?

Comment: In the case asked above I copy the objective-c file template (`cp -R Objective-C\ File.xctemplate destination/`) and change the #import line in `Empty File/___FILEBASENAME___.m` to @import.