# Change Xcode 11 Template files

Tags: ios, xcode, templates, xcode11

how can i change the Xcode Template files, when i want to create a new File? I searched online but the path to changes these wasn't correct with Xcode 11

I tried these:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Source
~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/File Templates/
```

But couldn't find the template files.

Comment: Searching for `XCode 11 templates` seems to return a lot of information. First link I selected - https://thoughtbot.com/blog/creating-custom-xcode-templates - appears to be helpful (I have nothing to do with that link). If that doesn't give you a solution, maybe try a few others?

Comment: this directory doesn't exist: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates` @DonMag

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the link I provided? The first task is to create the custom templates folder. In terminal, run: `mkdir -p ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Custom`. Now you have a folder where you can create your custom templates.

Comment: I understand that. But in the past it was possible to change apples own Templates

Answer (score 3):

Adding/detailling on Mark's answer:

Xcode path is for me:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates
```

Target path indeed matches (but Templates folder does not exist), so I did:

```
cp -fr /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates ~/Library/Developer/Xcode
```

Now, where are the C++ templates? Hidden in:

```
/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/MultiPlatform/Source/C++ File.xctemplate
```

What has `<cstdio>` to do in C++ project template files?? Someone at Apple's side has been sleeping here for some decades.

Anyways, it works but I have duplicated entries now. I tried removing the original folder but it does not work:
`sudo rm -rf /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates`

But anyways. Just picking the right files works. You can also rename the "C++ File.xctemplate" name... whatever is before "File" seems to work as a label in Xcode.

Alternatively, you can just change the templates directly in `/Applications/Xcode.app` but then suffer from having them overwritten after update.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's file templates are inside the Xcode app bundle.

```
Xcode/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates
```

You should not modify the file templates in the Xcode app bundle because you will lose them when you update Xcode. Copy the file templates you want to change to the user file template location.

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates
```

You may have to manually create some of the folders in this path. You may also want to create an additional folder to store your templates to make finding them easier when creating a new file.

After copying the file templates to the user file template location, you can make changes to the files.