# How to write a class with auto-generated stubs like UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c

I'm wanting to write a base class that, when derived from, contains code stubs like it does when you descend from a UITableViewController.  It automatically stubs in code, #warnings, and comments in the descended class.

For example: (if my class has the equivalent of an abstract method that they need to implement then it should appear in the new class automatically.)

-(int)thisNeedsToBeImplemented{
``#warning Incomplete implementation, return the int value needed.
}

I haven't been able to find a relevant article.

Comment: You are looking to create your own Xcode file templates. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode

Comment: Thanks! I will dig in.